# bootstrap div collapse and expand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to expand and collapse div elements with same id seperately when i click different buttons.

here is my HTML code

```
<body>
    <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dem">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show Status
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="dem">
        <p>This is first</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dem">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show Status
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="dem">
        <p>This is Second</p>
    </div>
    <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dem">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show Status
    </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="dem">
        <p>This is Third</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Here is my script

```
$(function(){

    $('#dem').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-up"></span> Hide Status');
    })
    $('#dem').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
        $('#button').html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span> Show Status');
    })
})
```

When I click the first button it expands and when I click second or third button the content of first button collapses.The content is not expanding for other buttons.I know I am missing some script code but i don't know what the code is.

Comment: ID values have to be unique. Use classes instead.

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one element in the document with the same id. If you want to group elements together for fetching via Javascript you should give them a common class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDs should always be DISTINCT.

Change these to classes ... since you are using jQuery, you can do something like this inside the click events ...

```
$(".className").hide()
$(".className").show()
$(".className").toggle()
```

Assuming they have different ID, the change would simply be something like ...

```
$("#button1").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
    $(".className").hide()
  } else {
    $(".className").show()
  }
});
```